# paragraph descriptors in longtable

Tags: longtable

I'd like to use "p" formatting in my longtable, and I'd like each column to be about 1 inch wide. I understand that there's some intercolumn spacing, so I used `@{}` to suppress that as much as possible. And I also understand that the vertical lines between cells take up a little space. Anyhow, I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{0.53in}\rule{4in}{0.4pt}

\noindent\begin{longtable}%
{%
@{}|p{1in}%
@{}|p{1in}%
@{}|p{1in}%
@{}|p{1in}|@{}}\hline%
ABC&  &  &   \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This produces a longtable that's about 4.5 inches wide, i.e., each column is about 1/8 inch wider than what I asked for. Sure, I can fiddle with the numbers, but this table is being generated by a program, so it'd be nice to get it right in some way that doesn't involve a brilliant tailor.

Comment: `@{}` on both sides of the `|`.

Comment: You are my new hero. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table will be 4in plus 2pt wide (because of the five rules' width).

Note that `\noindent` does nothing at all in front of a `longtable`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  @{\vline}p{1in}
  @{\vline}p{1in}
  @{\vline}p{1in}
  @{\vline}p{1in}
  @{\vline}
}
\hline
Abc & Def & Ghi jkl mno pqr stu & vw xyz \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the text will touch the rules.

[image]

If you want to have the rules just in the document preparation phase, it could be handy to define a new column type. In the example below I redefine the column type just to emulate what happens if you switch the comment in the two lines in the preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\newcolumntype{?}{@{\vline}}\newcommand{\yline}{\hline}
%\newcolumntype{?}{@{}}\newcommand{\yline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?
}
\yline
Abc & Def & Ghi jkl mno pqr stu & vw xyz \\
\yline
\end{longtable}

% just to show what happens if you switch the comments in the preamble
\newcolumntype{?}{@{}}\renewcommand{\yline}{}

\begin{longtable}{
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?p{1in}
  ?
}
\yline
Abc & Def & Ghi jkl mno pqr stu & vw xyz \\
\yline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how much the "rules" are going to "cost". To be honest, I'm using them only in the debugging/layout phase, so having the text crammed up against them is exactly the desired behavior.

Comment: @John Yes, the default value for the rule's width is 0.4pt

Comment: @John I added some code to ease the transition from the debugging to the final stage.

Comment: That's similar to what I've got --- "\vb" is defined to be a vertical-bar-or-nothing, and \oline is defined to be an \hline-or-nothing. And the "debug" macro turns both of them (and some other stuff) on and off. I definitely like the use of "newcolumntype" though --- very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised table-spec for others to copy from, based on @daleif's comment:

```
\noindent\begin{longtable}%
{%
@{}|@{}p{1in}%
@{}|@{}p{1in}%
@{}|@{}p{1in}%
@{}|@{}p{1in}@{}|@{}}\hline%
ABC&  &  &   \\\hline
\end{longtable}
```